# "Where Not In" in LINQ to EF4

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

Is there a direct translation between this SQL Statement to LINQ?

```
Select ProductId 
From ProductReport
Where ProductId NOT IN(Select ProductId From ClientProduct Where ClientId = CAST('06ae6be1-ca94-44c9-bd30-f1d4f3ac3264' AS uniqueidentifier))
```

I can achieve the same thing with two LINQ queries, but I'd rather use one query and hit the database once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from p in ProductReport
        where !ClientProduct.Any(c => 
           c.ClientId == new Guid("06ae6be1-ca94-44c9-bd30-f1d4f3ac3264") && 
           p.ProductId == c.ProductId)
        select p.ProductId;
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you have navigations in your model -- [and you should](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

```
var clientId = new Guid("06ae6be1-ca94-44c9-bd30-f1d4f3ac3264");
var q = from pr in Context.ProductReports
        where !pr.Clients.Any(c => c.ClientId == clientId)
        select pr.ProductId;
```